# Datetime indexing in Mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

Here is table

```
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| datecolumn | datetime | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Data in table

```
+---------------------+
| datecolumn          |
+---------------------+
| 2007-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2007-01-03 00:00:00 |
| 2008-01-03 00:00:00 |
| 2009-01-03 00:00:00 |
| 2010-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2010-01-02 00:00:00 |
| 2010-01-03 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+



EXPLAIN select * from test_date_index use key (datecolumn) where datecolumn>='2010-01-02 00:00:00';
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_date_index | index | datecolumn    | datecolumn |  9     | NULL |    7 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why mysql use 7 rows to retreive 1 row?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The explain shows that it does (the `key` column). So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Could you please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE test_date_index`?

Comment: 7 refers to the index length **in characters** not columns

Comment: I mean rows count in EXPLAIN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does use the index.

It (most probably) does not use the range access, since the table has so few records that searching for the first record of the range is in fact more expensive than just traversing the index and filtering the values.

When you add more values into the table, the range access is applied (since it's considered cheaper now) and `COUNT` shows `1`,  since you only have one record satisfying the condition.

Comment: The problem is when I'm adding a few values to a table I receive rows count 1 in EXPLAIN with the same query.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `test_date_index` (
  `datecolumn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `datecolumn` (`datecolumn`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8